# Antenna reception problem

Tags: electrical-engineering

Here's one for any of you electronics experts. On the 2nd story of my house, I have a TV antenna. It reaches a height of about 5 ft above the house, and the mounting bracket is attached to the back wall of the restroom. The downlead cable runs into the attic, through a preamp and on to the tv's throughout the house. Now...here is the puzzler...anytime someone goes up to the restroom and opens the door, the picture on all of the tv's will start tiling badly...before that, it was crystal clear....once the person comes out, opening and closing the door again, it will become clear. Now, why in the world would opening and closing the door of the restroom affect the signal from an antenna mounted behind the restroom and at least 5 foot higher than it's roof? I thought the family was nuts when they first told of this...I have tested and retested, it makes no sense at all, but I can't deny that it does happen.Anyone have a theory?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question : does the tiling occur only when the door is open? Or as long as there's a person inside? I think the second one. And bonus info: is the door wooden or anyhow metallic ?

Comment: is the antenna mast grounded? No idea about the door, but improving the ground may help.

Comment: Very probably the effect is due to local RF reflections that distort the signal strength and phase.  I expect the phenomenon is related to the position of the mass of a person in the room (the door is a red herring).  This is easily tested with a foil shield such as cooking foil or the metallized bubble insulation for a water tank between the antenna and the person. With the shield grounded the effect will be greatly reduced. Moving the external antenna a few feet will likely solve the problem.

Comment: Remember the antenna is feeding a very sensitive receiver - and with the preamp, all of the signal, including noise is amplified.

Answer (score 0):

What is the person doing in the bathroom? Are they communicating with aliens via a similar or harmonic frequency? HeHe... Honestly, the door is probably a red herring as mentioned, unless it is metal. Add a foil or metallic shield between. Perhaps ground the antenna post to a nearby pipe. Remove the pre-amp from the line and see what happens. The interference is likely RF, so any slight change will minimize or eliminate the problem. Is it possible the shield of the cable is nicked, or grounded on a metal edge? Is the cable shielded on one or both ends between the antenna or pre-amp? But eliminate the pre-amp as a source first.